# Importing Functions from Different "Modules"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery, coming from a Python and Java background, so I'm having trouble getting used to how working across different .js files works. I have an HTML file that imports the following scripts:

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/forms.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/workout1Alt.js"></script>
```

The last two are mine. In forms.js, I have a general function, `validateNumberForm`, that I want to be able to use in my more specific `workout1Alt.js` form. The form's signature looks like this:

```
var validateNumberForm = function(id)
```

I invoke the `validateNumberForm` in `workout1Alt.js` like this:

```
validateNumberForm('#squatsForm');
```

But I get this error:

```
Reference Issue: Cannot find variable validateNumberForm.
```

Can someone show me the best practices of how to do something like this?

Comment: The code extract you show from both JS files has `validateNumberForm` without an `s` on the end, but in your description and in the error message you have `validateNumberForms` _with_ an `s`. Are you sure you've got the spelling consistent in both files?

Comment: typo -- it's consistent in the code; edited to reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're wrapping the definition inside of a jQuery ready handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
    var validateNumberForm = function(id) { /* ... */ };
    // ...
});
```

That makes `validateNumberForm` only available in there. If you want it to be available to other files, you can move it out of the ready handler:

```
var validateNumberForm = function(id) { /* ... */ };
$(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Or you can explicitly export it:

```
$(function() {
    var validateNumberForm = function(id) { /* ... */ };
    window.validateNumberForm = validateNumberForm;
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Cool. One thing: I'm guessing that window.validateNumberForm method isn't exactly preferable? I tried that first but it led to some strange behavior that wasn't present when I just declared the function outside of the jQuery block.

Comment: @user1427661: Correct; defining it inside of the `ready` block makes it available only when the rest of the page has loaded. Defining it outside makes it available as soon as that bit of code has loaded.